# How to save text from TextView in word file?

Tags: android, textview, speech-to-text

I am designing a speech-to-text android application where I display the converted text in a textview. I want to save the converted text in the form of a word file/pdf on the user's device. Can somebody tell me how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To create a `.pdf` file

```
// create a new document
 PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

 // crate a page description
 PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 1).create();

 // start a page
 Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

 // draw something on the page
 View content = getContentView();
 content.draw(page.getCanvas());

 // finish the page
 document.finishPage(page);
 . . .
 // add more pages
 . . .
 // write the document content
 document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

 // close the document
 document.close();
```

for more detail please have a look on below link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html
I hope, it will work.

Comment: You "hope" it will work? Can you please post a code snippet to make this an answer?

Comment: It is not working. "PdfDocument cannot be resolved" is the error. I have imported android.graphics.* . Still it is showing the same error. Can you please help me resolve it!